# GCC/G++ Errors Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: gcc, clang, osx-yosemite

since some weeks, I'm working with a new Mac which works with OS X Yosemite (Version 10.10.3). I figured out a lot of trouble installing programs from source, why I already changed the compiler to, e.g., gcc 4.2, 4.7, and 4.9. Furthermore, I "removed" the connection to clang, but also this produces still errors during compiling. However, doing the same on a Mac OS X machine version 10.7.5 works fine. There, gcc version 4.2.1 is running.

Here's an example error message, I get typing make in the command line:

```
cc -O2   -c -o swat.o swat.c
In file included from swat.c:25:
./swat.h:85:35: warning: '/*' within block comment [-Wcomment]
  /*  int *maxstu_vec; NOT NEEDED /* array of length length + 1, used to hold row of scores,
                                  ^
swat.c:29:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
compare_scores(entry1, entry2)
^
swat.c:35:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
compare_z_scores(entry1, entry2)
^
swat.c:42:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
compare_E_values(entry1, entry2)
^
swat.c:49:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
main(argc,argv)
^
swat.c:75:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'get_parameters' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  get_parameters(argc, argv, "swat"); 
  ^
swat.c:85:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'alloc_hist' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  alloc_hist();
  ^
swat.c:86:10: warning: implicit declaration of function 'get_next_file_entry' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  while (get_next_file_entry(qdb)) {
         ^
swat.c:95:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'notify' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    notify("Searching: ");
    ^
swat.c:98:12: warning: implicit declaration of function 'append_seq_entry' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        s_entry = append_seq_entry(sdb);
                  ^
swat.c:110:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'set_score' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        set_score(s_entry, score);
        ^
swat.c:127:57: warning: implicit declaration of function 'get_seq_length' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        score = parameters->align(q_profile, get_seq(s_entry), get_seq_length(s_entry), 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                                                               ^
swat.c:146:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'initialize_hist' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    initialize_hist(); 
    ^
swat.c:155:7: warning: implicit declaration of function 'update_hist' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
      update_hist(score_entry, 0);
      ^
swat.c:158:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'process_hist' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    process_hist();
    ^
swat.c:172:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'fit_log_n' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        fit_log_n(q_length);
        ^
swat.c:175:4: warning: implicit declaration of function 'find_z' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
          find_z(score_entry);
          ^
swat.c:195:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'reject_entry' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
          if (!reject_entry(score_entry)) nz++; /* assumes Smith-Waterman */
               ^
swat.c:202:7: warning: implicit declaration of function 'new_est_lambda_K' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
      new_est_lambda_K(q_length, score_entries, last_score_entry);
      ^
swat.c:242:24: warning: '&&' within '||' [-Wlogical-op-parentheses]
        if (parameters->use_n && score_entry >= score_entries + parameters->max_num_alignments
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
swat.c:242:24: note: place parentheses around the '&&' expression to silence this warning
        if (parameters->use_n && score_entry >= score_entries + parameters->max_num_alignments
                              ^
            (                                                                                 )
swat.c:243:24: warning: '&&' within '||' [-Wlogical-op-parentheses]
         || parameters->use_z && score_entry->z < parameters->z_cutoff || !score_entry->score) 
         ~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
swat.c:243:24: note: place parentheses around the '&&' expression to silence this warning
         || parameters->use_z && score_entry->z < parameters->z_cutoff || !score_entry->score) 
                              ^
            (                                                         )
swat.c:256:29: warning: data argument not used by format string [-Wformat-extra-args]
               score_entry->score, score_entry->z, e_value, score_entry->E);
                                   ^
swat.c:261:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'print_alignment' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        print_alignment(q_profile);
        ^
swat.c:266:65: warning: data argument not used by format string [-Wformat-extra-args]
                get_id(seq_num), get_seq_length(seq_num), score_entry->score, score_entry->z);
                                                                              ^
swat.c:272:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'free_profile' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    free_profile(q_profile);
    ^
25 warnings generated.
cc -O2   -c -o weibull.o weibull.c
In file included from weibull.c:25:
./swat.h:85:35: warning: '/*' within block comment [-Wcomment]
  /*  int *maxstu_vec; NOT NEEDED /* array of length length + 1, used to hold row of scores,
                                  ^
weibull.c:47:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
reject_entry(score_entry)
^
weibull.c:50:32: warning: '&&' within '||' [-Wlogical-op-parentheses]
  return (!parameters->nw_flag && !score_entry->score || score_entry->length < LENGTH_CUTOFF);
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~
weibull.c:50:32: note: place parentheses around the '&&' expression to silence this warning
  return (!parameters->nw_flag && !score_entry->score || score_entry->length < LENGTH_CUTOFF);
                               ^
          (                                          )
weibull.c:53:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
alloc_hist()
^
weibull.c:65:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
weibull.c:67:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
initialize_hist()
^
weibull.c:78:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
weibull.c:80:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
update_hist(score_entry, z_flag)
^
weibull.c:88:5: error: non-void function 'update_hist' should return a value [-Wreturn-type]
    return;
    ^
weibull.c:92:5: error: non-void function 'update_hist' should return a value [-Wreturn-type]
    return;
    ^
weibull.c:106:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
prune_hist(score_entry)
^
weibull.c:111:34: error: non-void function 'prune_hist' should return a value [-Wreturn-type]
  if (reject_entry(score_entry)) return;
                                 ^
weibull.c:127:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
process_hist()
^
weibull.c:155:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'fatalError' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    fatalError("No entries have scores exceeding -gap_init");
    ^
weibull.c:168:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
fit_log_n(q_length)
^
weibull.c:300:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
est_lambda_K(q_length) 
^
weibull.c:399:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
new_est_lambda_K(q_length, score_entries, last_score_entry) /* using non-extreme-value dist'n */
^
weibull.c:644:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
find_z(entry)
^
weibull.c:652:21: warning: implicit declaration of function 'make_log_table' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    if (!log_table) make_log_table();
                    ^
weibull.c:665:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
make_log_table()
^
17 warnings and 3 errors generated.
make: *** [weibull.o] Error 1
```

Maybe someone of you has any idea, what the problem could be???

I would be very glad for every answer :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution. The problem was, as I already feared, the compiler.
I installed a relatively new version (gcc 4.9), set this version as active and added the path in ~/.bash_profile (that was the most important step). Furthermore, I adopted the makefile. Opening a new terminal and typing "make" runs without errors.

Comment: This seems like my problem in compiling phrap. Can you add information how specifically you set this up? A code would be most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
weibull.c:88:5: error: non-void function 'update_hist' should return a value [-Wreturn-type]
    return;
    ^
weibull.c:92:5: error: non-void function 'update_hist' should return a value [-Wreturn-type]
    return;
    ^
```

and

```
weibull.c:111:34: error: non-void function 'prune_hist' should return a value [-Wreturn-type]
  if (reject_entry(score_entry)) return;
                                 ^
```

must return a vaule of type in given function's header.